# How to use setup.py console_script with native namespace packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm unable to define `console_scripts` for my Python package that utilizes the Python namespace packages structure.

I am following the Python namespace packages outlined in the [Python packaging document](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/). Specifically, I am using [native namespace packaging](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages) in Python 3.8.2.

I have created my project like this:

```
src
└── main
   └── python
      └── mynamespace-mypackage
         ├── mynamespace
         │  └── mypackage
         │     ├── __init__.py
         │     ├── __main__.py
         │     ├── module_a.py
         │     └── module_b.py
         └── setup.py
```

In `setup.py`, I write:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

PACKAGE = "mynamespace-mypackage"
VERSION = "0.1a"

setup(
    name=PACKAGE,
    version=VERSION,
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=["mynamespace.*"]),
    description="My fancy package",
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": {
            "do-some-stuff = mypackage.__main__:main"
        }
    }
)
```

When I install my project using pip by calling `pip install -e src/main/python/mynamespace-mypackage`, the package gets installed successfully. However, when I call `do-some-stuff` from command line, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'`.

I also tried modifying the `console_scripts` to be:

```py
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": {
            "do-some-stuff = mynamespace.mypackage.__main__:main"
        }
    }
```

but this also gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mynamespace.mypackage` when I run `do-some-stuff` from the command line.

How should I define the entry point of my program to correctly point to the `__main__:main` function of my package? Any help is much appreciated.

**Potential Workaround:**

Based on [setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#namespace-packages), If I add `__init__.py` to `mynamespace` directory with the following content

```py
__import__("pkg_resources").declare_namespace(__name__)
```

And modify `setup.py` by adding `namespace_packages=["mynamespace"]`, the entry points work.
I can confirm that this solves my problem. However, this is not ideal in my opinion. The Python packaging documentation explicitly states that when using native packaging, I should not add any `__init__.py` to the namespace directory.

**A minimal reproducible example:**

`src/main/python/mynamespace-mypackage/mynamespace/mypackage/__init__.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from .module_a import Hello
from .module_b import GoodBye

__all__ = ["Hello", "GoodBye"]
```

`src/main/python/mynamespace-mypackage/mynamespace/mypackage/__main__.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from . import Hello, GoodBye

def main() -> None:
    h = Hello()
    h.say_hi()
    g = GoodBye()
    g.say_bye()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`src/main/python/mynamespace-mypackage/mynamespace/mypackage/module_a.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


class Hello:
    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        print("Hello!")
```

`src/main/python/mynamespace-mypackage/mynamespace/mypackage/module_b.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


class GoodBye:
    def say_bye(self) -> None:
        print("Good Bye!")
```

Comment: This looks to me like it should work, there is nothing wrong that I could see, the workaround should not be necessary. I would maybe try to make sure to uninstall the package and install it again. Maybe delete the `mynamespace_mypackage.egg-info.egg-info` directory, before retrying.

Comment: How do you import in `__main__.py`? I suspect you have dropped `mynamespace` in the imports somewhere. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @hoefling I added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @sinoroc thanks for suggesting that, but uninstalling and removing the egg files don't help

Comment: I successfully reproduced your example. It works as expected with `"do-some-stuff = mynamespace.mypackage.__main__:main"` in `console_scripts`.

Comment: I updated setuptools from 41.2 to 46.1.3 and now everything works! There is no need for the workaround anymore. Thanks @sinoroc!

Comment: The issue still remains even with `setuptools` v57.4.0 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue was an out of date `setuptools` library. I was using `setuptools-41.2.0`. I upgraded to `setuptools-46.1.3` and now my minimal example works as expected. There is no need for the workaround.

```sh
pip install -U setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [pkgutil-style namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages) was the only way for me to get this to work even with `setuptools-52.0.0`

`src/main/python/mynamespace-mypackage/mynamespace/__init__.py`:

```
__path__ = __import__("pkgutil").extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

And adding the namespace to packages in `setup.py`:

```
packages=["mynamespace", "mynamespace.mypackage"])
```